# How to install IceCat 60.7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, icecat

I'm new to Linux and I can't make this. I've gone through many forums and I can't figure it out. This may be very simple but I haven't got it yet. I've tried those:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401437/how-can-i-install-gnu-icecat-on-a-debian-based-system
- https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/how-to-install-icecat-browser.366525/
- http://www.thegeeky.space/2016/05/how-to-install-icecat-gnuzilla-browser-in-Ubuntu-and-other-debian-distro.html
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-install-IceCat-web-browser

But I can't make it work.

Please explain each step clearly.

Comment: Please expand on "I can't make it work".

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IceCat for clear, complete instructions for Ubuntu. Since IceCat is not packaged for Ubuntu, it's more difficult to install than normal Ubuntu-provided software. If you are new, this may be a learning-curve issue. Use the 'Search' box at the top of each AskUbuntu page if you get stuck.

Comment: I followed the instructions on Ubuntu 23 but I always get  an errored new tab page upon browser startup